# AS3 hittest keeps hitting

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I have the following problem:
I want to keep a score when i "hittest". I use the following code:

```
private function fnMoveMap():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < vPipeMax; i++)
        {

            var tmpPipe = _conMap.getChildAt(i);
            //trace (tmpPipe.name);

            if (tmpPipe._HIT.hitTestPoint(_P.x, _P.y, true))
            {
                tmpPipe.visible = false;

                //stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setScore);
                vScores++;
                txtScores.text = vScores.toString();
                //break;
            }
            //reset pos
            if (tmpPipe.x < 0)
            {
                //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setScore);
                tmpPipe.visible = true;
                tmpPipe.x = 1050 - vXSpeed;
                tmpPipe.y = randomRangeMC(minPipeY, maxPipeY);
                //set score
                //vScores++;
                //txtScores.text = vScores.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                tmpPipe.x -= vXSpeed;

            }
        }
    }
```

the var vScores keeps counts for 4 to 8 times.
How can i just count one?

Comment: Well I don't know what `vPipeMax` is, but you're looping multiple times in that for loop (potentially), so my guess is that's why your score increments by 4-8 each time you trigger it.

Comment: vPipeMax is 3. I know its in a loop, but how can i keep it from multiple hittests?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `vScores` variable is incrementing by 4-8 is because you're looping multiple times with the `for` loop through `vPipeMax`.

You either need to restructure your code so that doesn't happen, or `break` out of the loop as soon as you increment the score.

- Adobe's documentation on `break`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#break